# set My Location Enabled for Locationpicker jquery plugin

Tags: google-maps, jquery-location-picker

I need to show a button on google map to get my current position.

I am using locationpicker plugin for populate google map options. Currently, I am using

> current_location:true

option, but it's doing nothing for me..

Answer (score 3):

Please use following fiddle provided with an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mi3afzal/ogsvzacz/2/

```
var map;
var faisalabad = {lat:31.4181, lng:73.0776};

function addYourLocationButton(map, marker) 
{
var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');

var firstChild = document.createElement('button');
firstChild.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
firstChild.style.border = 'none';
firstChild.style.outline = 'none';
firstChild.style.width = '28px';
firstChild.style.height = '28px';
firstChild.style.borderRadius = '2px';
firstChild.style.boxShadow = '0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
firstChild.style.cursor = 'pointer';
firstChild.style.marginRight = '10px';
firstChild.style.padding = '0px';
firstChild.title = 'Your Location';
controlDiv.appendChild(firstChild);

var secondChild = document.createElement('div');
secondChild.style.margin = '5px';
secondChild.style.width = '18px';
secondChild.style.height = '18px';
secondChild.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://maps.gstatic.com/tactile/mylocation/mylocation-sprite-1x.png)';
secondChild.style.backgroundSize = '180px 18px';
secondChild.style.backgroundPosition = '0px 0px';
secondChild.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
secondChild.id = 'you_location_img';
firstChild.appendChild(secondChild);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
    $('#you_location_img').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
});

firstChild.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var imgX = '0';
    var animationInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if(imgX == '-18') imgX = '0';
        else imgX = '-18';
        $('#you_location_img').css('background-position', imgX+'px 0px');
    }, 500);
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            marker.setPosition(latlng);
            map.setCenter(latlng);
            clearInterval(animationInterval);
            $('#you_location_img').css('background-position', '-144px 0px');
        });
    }
    else{
        clearInterval(animationInterval);
        $('#you_location_img').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
    }
});

controlDiv.index = 1;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(controlDiv);
 }

function initMap() {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: faisalabad
 });
var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: faisalabad
  });
  addYourLocationButton(map, myMarker);
  }

 $(document).ready(function(e) {
   initMap();
 });    `
```

Comment: To have the Your Location button big like the other buttons (Zoom In, ...) and position it in line with them, my changes: firstChild.style --> width and height = '40px'; secondChild.style --> margin = '8px', width and height = '24px', backgroundSize = '240px 24px'.